# Random timeout exceptions in Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout

I host a Rails 3.2 app on Heroku and get 2-3 timeouts within the Rails application each day. These are *not* H12 request timeouts, but rather timeouts that occur somewhere within the Rails stack. Thus, they actually generate exceptions on the site and appear in my Airbrake logs.

It seems to be completely random where the timeout occurs; sometimes it's within a gem like Formtastic, or within a HAML view, or within the ActiveRecord code. You can see examples of some of the backtraces here: https://gist.github.com/dpmccabe/5238273

This site doesn't get much traffic and runs well on two dynos (though they automatically scale up thanks to the Adept Scale add-on). The HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_WAIT_TIME header is usually low or zero, so I don't think it's a routing issue.  I even tried switching from Thin to Unicorn with no effect (my unicorn.rb is shown in the above gist).

The fact that these timeout exceptions seem to occur randomly throughout the application doesn't give me much to go on. I do have New Relic, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. Any ideas?

Comment: This happens to our app once or twice per day... Wish I could provide more help but I'm in the same boat!

Comment: +1 I'm also seeing this, with Unicorn / Rails 3.2 / Rack-Timeout at 15s / Heroku Cedar. I'll follow this thread and post any more details if I can discover them.

Comment: Just curious: What's your average throughput (RPMs) around the time of the timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

I also have been running into the same issue. While I haven't solved it yet, I thought I would chime in with what I've looked at so far. I'm using the rack-timeout gem (based on your backtraces, it looks like you are as well) and have the timeout set at 15 seconds. Looking at new relic, my average app server response time for any request is well under 200ms. Yet, like you, I get 2-3 errors a day that look like this:

```
undefined method `result' for #<Timeout::Error: execution expired>
```

The errors occur on a wide range of actions, with no action seeming to be particularly likely to generate one. The error even occurs on simple CRUD DELETE actions. I'm running a rails 3.2 app on Heroku's Cedar stack. I run two web dynos, each with 3 unicorn workers. They each consistently stay below the 512mb limit.

The only clue I've found so far is that I often see something like the following near my timeouts in my logs:

```
[AMBER] LOG: process 21289 acquired ShareLock on transaction 105259 after 32366.132 ms
```

Do you see something similar? It might be possible that a DB action locking a record is causing the timeout, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue on my application hosted on heroku.

I inspected the logs and found that few requests took more than 30 secs to process which resulted in the timeout errors on heroku.
In my case the issue was printing to logs, I had a staging server which had a lot of input and output data printed to the server logs which took more than 30 secs to print, heroku would assume that the request is still under process even after the response was received from the remote api as it hasn't completed printing the data to the logs yet.

So I removed all the print statement that would print the input(input xml data constructed by the code) and output(xml data received from the api) data to the logs.

1. So I would suggest you to check the logs and see if requests are taking more than 30 seconds to process
2. Check if you are printing data(for debugging purpose) that takes time to print on the logs.

Again, this might not be the answer to your question but this is how I solved mine. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I used the following to turn off logging:

Rack::Timeout.unregister_state_change_observer(:logger)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) the router will terminate the request if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete.
You can use a [rack-timeout gem](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) to find your bottlenecks. Just make your timeout less than 30 sec

```
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 15 # seconds
```

If you have several parallel requests, consider to use [Unicorn](http://blog.codeship.io/2012/05/06/Unicorn-on-Heroku.html)